# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Property 'TimeStamp' is missing the LoadColumnAttribute attribute'

Tags: dataframe, ml.net

Met "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Property 'TimeStamp' is missing the LoadColumnAttribute attribute'" when using mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile

```
private static void LoadDFData(string fullPathFile)
        {
            if(File.Exists(fullPathFile))
            { 
                //Create MLContext
                MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
                //Load Data
                IDataView data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<RawHistoricalPriceRecord>(fullPathFile, separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: true);
            }
        }

public class RawHistoricalPriceRecord
    {
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I am following the MSDN document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net

Can I know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved using the method below url:https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-c-dataframe-and-xplotploty

var df1 = DataFrame.LoadCsv("ohlcdata.csv");

The sample file can be downloaded here: http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/ex-ohlcbasic.html

[image]